# RuntimeError: Attempting CUDA graph capture of step() for an instance of Adam but this instance was constructed with capturable=False

Tags: python, windows, optimization, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I get an error when I run this code `!python train.py` (KiU-Net 3D) in Google Colab Pro in Windows using Python and Pytorch library, which is the following:

```
File "train.py", line 86, in <module>
    opt.step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py", line 68, in wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 140, in wrapper
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 23, in _use_grad
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 178, in step
    self._cuda_graph_capture_health_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 103, in _cuda_graph_capture_health_check
    raise RuntimeError("Attempting CUDA graph capture of step() for an instance of " +
RuntimeError: Attempting CUDA graph capture of step() for an instance of Adam but this instance was constructed with capturable=False.
```

This is the *train.py* file where I get the error in *opt.step()*:

```
import os
from time import time

import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

from visdom import Visdom

from dataset.dataset import Dataset

from loss.Dice import DiceLoss
from loss.ELDice import ELDiceLoss
from loss.WBCE import WCELoss
from loss.Jaccard import JaccardLoss
from loss.SS import SSLoss
from loss.Tversky import TverskyLoss
from loss.Hybrid import HybridLoss
from loss.BCE import BCELoss

from net.models import net

import parameter as para

viz = Visdom(port=666)
step_list = [0]
win = viz.line(X=np.array([0]), Y=np.array([1.0]), opts=dict(title='loss'))


os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = para.gpu
cudnn.benchmark = para.cudnn_benchmark


net = torch.nn.DataParallel(net).cuda()
net.train()

print(para.training_set_path)
train_ds = Dataset(os.path.join(para.train_ct_path, 'ct'), os.path.join(para.train_seg_path, 'seg'))


train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, para.batch_size, True, num_workers=para.num_workers, pin_memory=para.pin_memory)


loss_func_list = [DiceLoss(), ELDiceLoss(), WCELoss(), JaccardLoss(), SSLoss(), TverskyLoss(), HybridLoss(), BCELoss()]
loss_func = loss_func_list[5]


opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=para.learning_rate)


lr_decay = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(opt, para.learning_rate_decay)


alpha = para.alpha

start = time()
for epoch in range(para.Epoch):

    lr_decay.step()

    mean_loss = []

    for step, (ct, seg) in enumerate(train_dl):

        ct = ct.cuda()
        seg = seg.cuda()

        outputs = net(ct)
        print(len(outputs))

        loss1 = loss_func(outputs[0], seg)
        loss2 = loss_func(outputs[1], seg)
        loss3 = loss_func(outputs[2], seg)
        loss4 = loss_func(outputs[3], seg)

        loss = (loss1 + loss2 + loss3) * alpha + loss4

        mean_loss.append(loss4.item())

        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        # opt.param_groups[0]['capturable'] = True #https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/80809
        opt.step()


        if step % 5 is 0:
            
            step_list.append(step_list[-1] + 1)
            viz.line(X=np.array([step_list[-1]]), Y=np.array([loss4.item()]), win=win, update='append')
            
            print('epoch:{}, step:{}, loss1:{:.3f}, loss2:{:.3f}, loss3:{:.3f}, loss4:{:.3f}, time:{:.3f} min'
                  .format(epoch, step, loss1.item(), loss2.item(), loss3.item(), loss4.item(), (time() - start) / 60))

    mean_loss = sum(mean_loss) / len(mean_loss)

   
    if epoch % 50 is 0 :

        
        torch.save(net.state_dict(), '/content/drive/MyDrive/CS/Models/KiU-Net/LiTS/saved_networks/net{}-{:.3f}-{:.3f}.pth'.format(epoch, loss, mean_loss))

    
    if epoch % 40 is 0 and epoch is not 0:
        alpha *= 0.8
```

I expect to run the neural network as normal training. This is the architecture of KiU-Net 3D in case there is an error there (*models.py*):

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.split(sys.path[0])[0])

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

import parameter as para

class segnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, training):
        super(segnet, self).__init__()
        self.training = training
        self.encoder1 = nn.Conv3d(1, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 16, 10, 10
        self.encoder2=   nn.Conv3d(32, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 8, 3, 3
        self.encoder3=   nn.Conv3d(64, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.encoder4=   nn.Conv3d(128, 256, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.encoder5=   nn.Conv3d(256, 512, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        
        self.decoder1 = nn.Conv3d(512, 256, 3, stride=1,padding=1)  # b, 16, 5, 5
        self.decoder2 =   nn.Conv3d(256, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 8, 15, 1
        self.decoder3 =   nn.Conv3d(128, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)  # b, 1, 28, 28
        self.decoder4 =   nn.Conv3d(64, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.decoder5 =   nn.Conv3d(32, 3, 3, stride=1, padding=1) # self.decoder5 =   nn.Conv3d(32, 2, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        
        self.map4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(3, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(2, 1, 1, 1),
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(1, 1, 1), mode='trilinear'), # nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(1, 2, 2), mode='trilinear')
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # 128*128 尺度下的映射
        self.map3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(64, 1, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(4, 4, 4), mode='trilinear'), #nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(4, 8, 8), mode='trilinear')
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # 64*64 尺度下的映射
        self.map2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(128, 1, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(8, 8, 8), mode='trilinear'), #nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(8, 16, 16), mode='trilinear')
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        # 32*32 尺度下的映射
        self.map1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(256, 3, 1, 1), #nn.Conv3d(256, 1, 1, 1)
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(16, 16, 16), mode='trilinear'), #nn.Upsample(scale_factor=(16, 32, 32), mode='trilinear'),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        self.soft = nn.Softmax(dim =1)

    def forward(self, x):

        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder1(x),2,2))
        t1 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder2(out),2,2))
        t2 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder3(out),2,2))
        t3 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder4(out),2,2))
        t4 = out
        out = F.relu(F.max_pool3d(self.encoder5(out),2,2))
        
        # t2 = out
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder1(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # print(out.shape,t4.shape)
        out = torch.add(F.pad(out,[0,0,0,0,0,1]),t4)
        output1 = self.map1(out)
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder2(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # out = torch.add(out,t3)
        output2 = self.map2(out)
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder3(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # out = torch.add(out,t2)
        output3 = self.map3(out)
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder4(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        # out = torch.add(out,t1)
        
        out = F.relu(F.interpolate(self.decoder5(out),scale_factor=(2,2,2),mode ='trilinear'))
        output4 = self.map4(out)
        # print(out.shape)
        # print(output1.shape,output2.shape,output3.shape,output4.shape)
        if self.training is True:
            return output1, output2, output3, output4
        else:
            return output4

def init(module):
    if isinstance(module, nn.Conv3d) or isinstance(module, nn.ConvTranspose3d):
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(module.weight.data, 0.25)
        nn.init.constant_(module.bias.data, 0)


net =segnet(training=True)
net.apply(init)

# 计算网络参数 (Calculating network parameters)
print('net total parameters:', sum(param.numel() for param in net.parameters()))
```

And this is how I calculate the loss function (*Tversky.py*):

```
"""

Tversky loss
"""

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class TverskyLoss(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, pred, target):

        smooth = 1e-7
        pred = pred.squeeze()
        target = target.squeeze()

        pred = torch.argmax(pred, dim=0).flatten().to(torch.int64)
        target = target.flatten().to(torch.int64)
        # print(pred.shape)
        # print(target.shape)

        pred_f = F.one_hot(pred,  num_classes=3)[...,1:]
        target_f = F.one_hot(target, num_classes=3)[...,1:]
        # print(pred_f.shape)
        # print(target_f.shape)

        intersection = torch.sum(pred_f * target_f, axis=1)
        denominator = torch.sum(pred_f + target_f, axis=-1)
        # print(intersection.shape)
        # print(denom.shape)

        dice = 1 - torch.mean((2. * intersection / (denominator + smooth)))
        dice.requires_grad = True

        return dice
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why**

Torch optimizers throw `Attempting CUDA graph capture of step()...` if [they detect](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/06326a7721b3944d41641841719d3e012feec113/torch/optim/optimizer.py#L171) that the current CUDA stream (queue of operations to be run on the GPU) is actively [recording](https://pytorch.org/blog/accelerating-pytorch-with-cuda-graphs/#api-overview) ("capturing") operations.

Since you're seeing this error during `opt.step()`, some code that runs prior to `opt.step()` is probably starting CUDA graph / stream capture for the current (default) stream, but never turning capture mode off.

You can verify this hypothesis with `print("Capturing:", torch.cuda.is_current_stream_capturing())` before `opt.step()`. Based on the error message, this will print `Capturing: True`, but you want `Capturing: False`.

You may be able to use `print("Capturing:", torch.cuda.is_current_stream_capturing())` to narrow down what part of the code is initiating graph / stream capture.

**Fix?**

Without knowing which part of the code is initiating the graph / stream capture, it's hard to suggest an elegant fix.

If the stream capture occurs before your training loop, you might be able to work around the issue by just wrapping your training loop in a dedicated stream (which won't be in capture mode):

```py
training_loop_stream = torch.cuda.Stream()
torch.cuda.synchronize() # make sure model is on device
with torch.cuda.stream(training_loop_stream):
    # training loop, now using this dedicated stream...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Actually, I run `print("Capturing:", torch.cuda.is_current_stream_capturing())` just before the line `opt.step()` and I got `Capturing: False` (that is what I want), but you said that it will print `True` (that is the problem of my code) . How can this happen?

Comment: I could solve the problem by adding in the `torch.optim.Adam` the following: `capturable=True` -> `opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=para.learning_rate, capturable=True)`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make sense to me either. `opt.step()` should call this grad check [first thing](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/adam.py#L231), unless you are using a pre/post hook in the optimizer (which wraps [around the step call](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/6f4dea562de0a1388f3d63b5ae1ecc15a47d254f#diff-8015a6c74af00fb9fd8c6fc7f7e5b206f8f8cce0ea6fe2f0653bf62c146c3892R213)).  You may need to use a debugger (pdb / ipdb) to go into `opt.step()` and see what happens before the internal `torch.cuda.is_current_stream_capturing` check succeeds.